# How to specify the header path while compiling a static library for MacOSX?

Tags: xcode, macos

I created a new project for compiling a static library (e.g.: libmyproduct.a) for MacOSX.

As seen in the second screenshot, I need to specify the header path for the project (for example, path for the boost header files), but I don't see any option in the IDE! Usually, there is an option such as header-path for me to add a path to. Without specifying a header-path, there is no chance I'll ever be able to compile my source code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the same by switching to the `All` tab in the target `Build Settings` and looking for `Header Search Paths`
[image]